# Definite integral help me please?Is this correct?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

We have the integral

$$A=\frac{2}{\pi} \left( \int_0^π - \frac{Bt}{\pi} \cos(nt) \, dt+ \int_0^π B \cos(nt) \, dt \right).$$

My professor wrote the result as

$$A=\frac{4B}{\pi^2 n^2}.$$

To be honest, now that I'm solving this at home I think he made some mistakes.

First for

$$\int_0^π (-Bt/ \pi)\cos(nt) \, dt$$

he wrote that for $n=\text{odd}$ we have $B/ \pi$ as a result. This is correct. And for $n=\text{even}$ we have $0$ as a result. I'm reluctant about this.

Now for the second part

$$\int_0^π  B \cos(nt) \, dt$$

we have $[B \sin(\pi n)]/n$ as a result (This is correct) and for  $n=\text{even}$ we have $0$ as a result.

How can it be that the result is

$$A=\frac{4B}{\pi^2 n^2}$$

and do you think there are mistakes along the way? I checked this on wolfram alpha and the result wasnt the same as my prof's.

Answer (score 0):

Let's write it as one integral, just by combining the two terms -
$$
A = \frac{2B}{\pi^2} \int_0^{\pi} \left( \pi - t \right) \cos (nt) \ \mathrm{d} t.
$$
Let's do integration by parts on this integral.
\begin{align}
\int_0^{\pi} \left( \pi - t \right) \cos (nt) \ \mathrm{d} t & = \left[{\pi-t \over n} \sin (nt)\right]_0^{\pi} + \frac{1}{n}\int_0^{\pi} \sin(nt) \ \mathrm{d} t, \\
& = \left[0-0\right] + \frac{1}{n^2}\left[-\cos(nt)\right]_0^{\pi}, \\
& = -\frac{1}{n^2}\left[\cos(n\pi) - 1\right].
\end{align}
Now, when $n$ is even, the entire integral (and thus $A$) vanishes. However when $n$ is odd, we get $\cos(n\pi)=-1$, so the value of the above integral is $2/n^2$. Thus
$$
A=
\begin{cases}
0, \qquad & \mbox{if} \  n  \ \mbox{is even} \\
\displaystyle \frac{4B}{n^2\pi^2}, \quad & \mbox{if} \  n  \ \mbox{is odd} 
\end{cases}
$$